# How to compare two columns from two DFs keeping some column constants and print row?

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I'm working on a project where I have to find the changes done in second sheet (specific column) as compare to primary/Master sheet.
after that I wanted to print or save the complete row in which changes are found.
here are more details.
both the excel sheets have many columns 
my master sheet has data something like as follows:

```
 TID    LOC HECI    RR  UNIT    SUBD    S   EUSE    INV ACT CAC FMT CKT DD   
SCID    CUSTOMER    F&E/SERVICE ID  BVAP    PORD    AUTH    RULE    ST  RGN
CHCGILDTO3P050101D  CHCGILDTO3P M3MSA0S1RA  0501.01D    1A1              IE D   STR3RA8 S   CL/HFFS/688898 /LGT 2018-07-21      BLOOMBERG LP     DS3-16668545   WMS881282       E.485339        IL  N
CHCGILDTO3P050101D  CHCGILDTO3P M3MSA0S1RA  0501.01D    1A2             IE  J           DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466    2019-03-22              WMS881282       E.485339        IL  N
CHCGILDTO3P050101D  CHCGILDTO3P M3MSA0S1RA  0501.01D    1A3             IE  J           DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466    2019-03-22              WMS881282       E.485339        IL  N
CHCGILDTO3P050101D  CHCGILDTO3P M3MSA0S1RA  0501.01D    1A4             IE  J           DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466    2019-03-22              WMS881282       E.485339        IL  N
CHCGILDTO3P050101D  CHCGILDTO3P M3MSA0S1RA  0501.01D    1A5             IE  J           DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466    2019-03-22              WMS881282       E.485339        IL  N
```

---

and my second sheet has data as follows :

```
  HECI  UNIT    INV SUB ACT CKT PACT    DD  LOC RR
M3MSA0S1RA  1A1 IE      $   CL/HFFS/688898 /LGT D   72118   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
M3MSA0S1RA  1A2 IE      J   DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466        32219   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
M3MSA0S1RA  1A3 IE      J   DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466        32219   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
M3MSA0S1RA  1A4 IE      J   DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466        32219   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
M3MSA0S1RA  1A5 IE      J   DNA UNDER DECOM EID 2466        32219   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
```

so first i want to check if the values of LOC HECI RR & UNIT are same in both the sheets I want to move forward and comapre ACT column and print the difference as output.

for example you can see row #1
in Master data ACT is 'D' and where as in second sheet its changes to '$'

so I want output something like 
related complete row which says its changes from 'D' to '$'

this seems very complicated to me as I'm at beginning stage of python and pandas.

I tried using loops but unable to execute also if I use too much loop that's not the pandas way I believe

here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.read_excel("Master Database.xlsx")
df2 = pd.read_excel("CHCGILDTO3P_0501.01D.xlsx")
d1_act = df1['ACT']
d2_act = df2['ACT']
for index1, row1 in df1.iterrows():
    for index2, row2 in df2.iterrows():
        if(row1['LOC'],row1['HECI'],row1['RR']) ==(row2['LOC'],row2['HECI'],row2['RR']):
            for x in d1_act and y in d2_act:
                #print(x,y)
                if x != y:

                    print (x, y) # not getting how to print complete respective row

                else:
                    pass
        else:
            pass
```

I want ouput like:

```
M3MSA0S1RA  1A1 IE      $   CL/HFFS/688898 /LGT D   72118   CHCGILDTO3P 0501.01D
```

changes from 'D to '$'

please assist !
thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) for your case like this:

```
df_result = master_df.merge(specific_df, on = ['LOC','HECI','RR'])
```

`df_result` will have the dataframe with complete rows which are matching on 'LOC','HECI' and 'RR' columns. Next, you can check the values in `df_result` under columns named `ACT_x` (from `master_df`) and `ACT_y` (from `specific_df`) to see if there is a difference and print it out as required:

```
print(df_result[df_result.ACT_x != df_result.ACT_y])
```

Comment: thank you so much.. it helps..I added following code for comparison                             indx = df_result[df_result['ACT_x'] != df_result['ACT_y']].index
print(df_result.iloc[indx])

Comment: Yes, I have updated the suffix in my answer. It will be _x and _y by default. Please mark it as the answer if it helped solve the issue.

Comment: You need not do a .index and then .iloc in the print() as you have mentioned in your comment. I have updated my answer with the direct statement to achieve what you want.